# How to pass parameters into an eventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, parameters, event-listener, queryselector

I need to read the values from inputs that I'm creating dynamically on the DOM.

When I click submit I need to obtain all the inputs, I do it with an event to a querySelectorAll but I need this last one to be outside the evenListener click because otherwise each time I press "submit" I get all the inputs again and repeat everything in my instance of object, where every input goes.

How can I get all the inputs information just once and not adding more repeat instances of the object in each submit?

```
 let containerTasks = [];


const btnAddTask = document.getElementById("button-addon2");

const submitBtn = document.getElementById("btn__submitList");



class Tasks {
    constructor(name, index) {
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
    }
}


const myForm = document.createElement("form")
const myInputForms = myForm.setAttribute('class', 'my-InputForms');
mainTaskList.append(myForm)

btnAddTask.addEventListener("click", () => {


    inputSlot = document.createElement('input');
    inputSlot.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    inputSlot.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Ingresa tu tarea');
    inputSlot.setAttribute('class', 'input-forms');

    myForm.appendChild(inputSlot);


    let inputSubmit = document.createElement('input');
    inputSubmit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    inputSubmit.setAttribute('class', 'sending');
    myForm.appendChild(inputSubmit);



})


const myInput = document.querySelectorAll('.input-forms');


myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    myInput.forEach((myTask, index) => {
        containerTasks.push(new Tasks(myTask.value, `tarea ${index}`));
    })


    console.log(containerTasks)


});
```

Comment: What is your html structure for the above?

Comment: just look for the object in the array before pushing or use a `Map` or object to ensure no duplicates are added.

Comment: @obscure there it is the complete script, I'm creating dinamically each input with a click in btnAddTask, if you need the still html structure I can upload it to. Sorry I'm a complete newbie.. I apreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: At the moment I don't see an use for the extra submit buttons you're appending to each task. What's it good for?

Comment: Also I can't really reproduce the problem you're describing. The only thing that needs to be changed is moving the `const myInput = document.querySelectorAll('.input-forms');` line **inside** the submit buttons callback function to get an actual list of input elements. If you just run it once sometime before this list might come up empty.